# Drupal: Change the entire markup of poll / advanced poll

Tags: php, html, templates, drupal, drupal-modules

Is it possible to edit the entire markup of the core poll module or the advanced poll (they use roughly the same template)?

I am making a drupal site for a customer, who wants the poll to be stylized with a specific layout. Just applying CSS to whatever the poll renders by default is out of the question.

Is this possible without modifying core modules / templates, but rather extending them and how?

P.S.: I am quite new to drupal.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the core module itself is definitely not advisable. Drupal has a very flexible and powerful theming system that can allow you to overwrite the output of the core poll, advanced poll, or (for that matter) any content type.

What you need to understand that each poll you will create is, in Drupal parlance, a `node` whose content type is `poll`. Now, with this basic knowledge, based on whether you are  using Drupal 6 or 7, one of the following links will help you:

- [Drupal 6](http://drupal.org/node/1089642)
- [Drupal 7](http://drupal.org/node/17565)

Additionally, here's are some pages on [Poll specific theming information](https://www.google.com/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=drupal+poll+tpl.php).